# JNA get module from process by name

Tags: java, pointers, winapi, jna

I'm looking for a way to rewrite a function from C++ in Java where I'm getting a module entry from a process by it's name.
I'm not well experienced in JNA and it's hard for me to understand how pointers are implemented in Java.
Here is my C++ code.

```
ULONG GetModule(DWORD th32ProcessID, MODULEENTRY32* Entry, PCWSTR szModule) 
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, th32ProcessID);

    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
    ULONG dwError = ERROR_NOT_FOUND;

    Entry->dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    if (Module32FirstW(hSnapshot, Entry))
    {
        do 
        {
            if (!_wcsicmp(Entry->szModule, szModule))
            {
                dwError = NOERROR;
                break;
            }
        } while (Module32NextW(hSnapshot, Entry));
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);

    return dwError;
   }
   return GetLastError();
}
```

And here is my attempt to implement this in java:

```
    private Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W findModule(String module) {
    Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W moduleEntry = new Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W.ByReference();

    WinNT.HANDLE snapshot =
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
                    TH32CS_SNAPMODULE,
                    new WinDef.DWORD(pid)
            );

    if(snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if(Kernel32.INSTANCE.Module32FirstW(snapshot, moduleEntry)) {
            do {
                if(Arrays.toString(moduleEntry.szModule).equals(module)) {
                    return moduleEntry;
                }
            } while (Kernel32.INSTANCE.Module32NextW(snapshot, moduleEntry));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It always returns null.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're looking for `Arrays.toString` here. Take a look at its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char%5B%5D)):

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(char). Returns "null" if a is null.

So for example, a `char[]` array of `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }` would be stringified into `"[h, e, l, l, o]"`.

Since you just want to turn that char array into a string as-is, try using the [`String` class' constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])) which does just that.

```
if (module.equals(new String(moduleEntry.szModule))) {
    // ...
}
```

If you're not looking for an exact match, you could try `.contains()`.

Also, **remember to close the handle to the snapshot** with `CloseHandle` like in the C++ version! If you don't close the handle, your method leaks memory every time it is called.

```
private Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W findModule(String module) {
    Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W moduleEntry = new Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W.ByReference();

    WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
        TH32CS_SNAPMODULE,
        new WinDef.DWORD(pid)
    );

    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return null;
    }

    Tlhelp32.MODULEENTRY32W match = null;
    if (Kernel32.INSTANCE.Module32FirstW(snapshot, moduleEntry)) {
        do {
            if (module.equals(new String(moduleEntry.szModule))) {
                match = moduleEntry;
                break;
            }
        } while (Kernel32.INSTANCE.Module32NextW(snapshot, moduleEntry));
    }

    Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return match;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately my problem is not fixed. It still returns null. I think I've done something wrong with the JNA pointer stuff.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that the `dwSize` is not being set in the Java version but is being set in the native version.